# Is there any way to change all values in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a pandas data frame, which has values for example from `ID:ko00001` to `ID:ko99999`.

How could I change these values to `00001-99999`? And convert to integer?

Comment: Assuming all your values have 5 characters to remove before them: `df[col_name] = [int(i[5:]) for i in df[col_name]]` or `df[col_name] = df[col_name].str[5:].astype(int)`

Comment: You should provide an example data with some code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to attract good answers, it's important to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing code for what you've tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts. For example, [Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) seem appropriate

Comment: `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)`

Comment: or `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace('ID:ko', '').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized option would be:

```
df['col'].str[-5:].astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
0        1
1    99999
```